# Como obtener por Webservice una imagen de MySQL en base 64?

Tags: php, mysql, webservice

Hola amigos verán quiero obtener todos los registros de una tabla llamada CATEGORIAS con los campos IDCATEGORIA, NOMBRECATEGORIA, IMAGENCATEGORIA mediante un Webservice echo en PHP y MYSQL y me lo muestre en un JSON, el problema es que el Webservice solo me regresa IDCATEGORIA y NOMBRECATEGORIA pero IMAGENCATEGORIA no lo muestra, es mi primera vez en manejar Webservices con PHP, solo he ocupado Webservices con Java y hasta donde se en Java se necesitaba obtener el campo IMAGENCATEGORIA de la base de datos y convertir esa imagen en base64 para después así mostrarla como una cadena de caracteres en base64 junto a los demás datos ya formando el JSON, alguien sabría como implementar eso en mi código PHP, aquí les dejo el archivo PHP:

Meta.php

```
/**
 * Representa el la estructura de las metas
 * almacenadas en la base de datos
 */
require 'Database.php';

class Meta
{
    function __construct()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Retorna en la fila especificada de la tabla 'meta'
     *
     * @param $idMeta Identificador del registro
     * @return array Datos del registro
     */
    public static function getAll()
    {
        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM meta";
        try {
            // Preparar sentencia
            $comando = Database::getInstance()->getDb()->prepare($consulta);
            // Ejecutar sentencia preparada
            $comando->execute();

            return $comando->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

obtener_metas.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Obtiene todas las metas de la base de datos
 */

require 'Meta.php';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {

    // Manejar petición GET
    $metas = Meta::getAll();

    if ($metas) {

        $datos["estado"] = 1;
        $datos["metas"] = $metas;

        print json_encode($datos);
    } else {
        print json_encode(array(
            "estado" => 2,
            "mensaje" => "Ha ocurrido un error"
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: imprime metas para ver si trae efectivamente ese valor

Comment: Solo me aparece la palabra "Array" cuando imprimo metas

Comment: hacelo con print_r

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$metas' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/u558631550/public_html/obtener_metas.php on line 13

Comment: lo hiciste con print_r($metas); ? ese error es de que la variable no esta definida

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [IDCATEGORIA] => 1 [NOMBRECATEGORIA] => pirmeronombre [IMAGENCATEGORIA] => ‰PNG  IHDR``H‘¿³èIDATxíÚ1Š1@áWéFÝ»ªQ<Ë"{%7qŠM¶³I‹YÈïýõ@>ù›ÁÌÌÌÌÌžÙg23u°™ÉœØñ¶‰…:ðë×Çÿ¡˜+Ý.Ô “úw¿„¶4©æHS¸Ó4‡

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50397/discussion-between-sioesi-and-carlos-hernandez).